# Decision boundary in Linear Regression

Tags: linear-regression, logistic-regression

Does Linear regression have a decision boundary? If yes, then is it always linear? How is it different from when plotting decision boundary for logistic regression?

Answer (score 1):

**Linear Regression is used to predict continuous values** and **Logistic Regression is used to predict discrete values**. There is no point of having a decision boundary for a set of continuous set of values. That is why we don't talk about a decision boundary in Linear Regression.

Assume you have a decision boundary x = 5 for Linear Regression hypothesis function y = 1 + x (Assuming you have only one feature). How can you assign values when x > = 5 & x<5. If it was binary classification we could assign 0 & 1 ( true & false / yes & no etc.) This shows that if we are using a decision boundary we are already categorizing our output.